# How to indexing array propery inside laravel for loop NOT foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Laravel 5.3 prjects: i have e for loop and an object passed from my controller with property as array

My UserController@edit

```
return view('user.edit',compact('user'));
```

My user object have a array like property "Post" so $user->post return an array like

```
[0]=>'post1',
[1]=>'post2',
... more ...
```

in my view with BLADE i need to display 7 text field input box as array and fill it with array right value of $user->post property:

```
 @for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
        <input type="text" name="ingredients[]" value="{{ ($user->post)[$i] }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Post title">
    @endfor
```

this return error:

```
ErrorException in 600ad3d79a7e4216538932fc71b893314cf18166.php line 65:
Undefined offset: 2
```

the problem is the $i inside value attribute if i replace with 0 or 1 (hardcoded index value) it work but with loop index $i it fails??

any ideas how to indexing array property in a for loop on blade template engine?

note: i cannot user foreach loop.

thx alll

Comment: What's the exact output of `dd($user->post);` ?

Comment: [0=>'Post1',1=>'Post2']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont appear to be limiting your loop to only what actually exists in the array, so make the for loop stop at the max size of the array

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($user->post); $i++)
    <input type="text" name="ingredients[]" value="{{ $user->post[$i] }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Post title">
@endfor
```

Comment: Thx RiggsFolly nice, you save my life!